# Getting 503 service unavailable - Firebase Remote config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have started getting 503 service unavailable error from firebase while fetching remote config values.

```
Fetch failed! Server responded with an error.
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzd: 503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code": 503,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
      "reason": "backendError"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
  "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
}
```

I have firebase blaze plan and this error constantly appears. I think it started coming after upgrading to latest firebase remote config library.

```
long cacheExpiration = 4800;
    if (firebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
        cacheExpiration = 2;
    }
    firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {

            });
```

The current firebase dependencies that I am currently using is

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
```

Comment: That error indicates a problem on the backend, which I don't think your code should be able to cause. I don't see any recent outages on the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/), so you might want to  [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the firebase cdn.
Faced same issue, I just upgraded the firebase in my case and it worked.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/913